# Blender emission quality issue

Tags: transparency, emission

For some reason, the emission is very low quality when emitting from this partially transparent image. Any idea why?[image]

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "low quality"?

Comment: The sampling rate should improve this kind of artefacts